# Why doesn't map display anything?

Tags: swift2, xcode7, watchkit, watchos-2

I have the following in awakeWithContext():

```
    let coord = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.748433,longitude: -73.985656)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coord, span: MKCoordinateSpanMake(10, 10))
    mymap.setRegion(region)
```

mymap does have an IBOutlet to a map but nothing is displaying.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

It works fine in the iOS app but does nothing on the Watch.

Comment: "but nothing is displaying." what does that mean ? The map tiles are not showing or the map itself is not showing?

Answer (score 0):

Just try to set `AutoResizingMask` :

```
mymap.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight]
```

Also, try to disconnect and reconnect your outlet.

Comment: Use of unresolved identifier: UIViewAutoresizing. Tried reconnecting the outlet but still nothing.